# How to fix "Cannot save file" error in dev-c++

Tags: dev-c++

I'm have been working on this c file for some time and regularly saving it each time i execute the code. All of a sudden i can't save the file due to an error: "cannot save file D:\Applications\C\C_files\no_of_days.c"

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcoGJ.jpg).

I have been having the same error while trying to save different c files for a few days now (this never happened before).
On googling the error, i found only one suitable answer, there it was suggested to not use folder names with spaces for saving programs in dev-c++.

I did that but the problem still persists.

This is my first time asking a question on stack overflow, so forgive me for any mistakes that i may have made.

Edit: As a temporary solution for this issue, I copied the code and pasted the code into a new file and save it with a different name. After a few times of saving and execution, the same error occurs.
I did the abovementioned steps(making a new file....) 4 more time, and each time, after a few saves, the same error occurs.

Comment: Perhaps it's open in another editor too.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Please, include the error messages as text in the post instead of using images.

Comment: @WeatherVane no. however, it is being synced to google cloud after every change, if that is makes any difference.

Comment: @JuhoRutila thank you for the information, i did that now.

Comment: Why the `c` tag? There is literally no C code in this question.

Comment: @melpomene I included the c tag as the files i tried to save were in c. I'll remove it if that's not appropriate here.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you, you hint that the files may be in use by something else helped me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Conversely, it can be frustrating when I want to save a document I have edited, but the OS forbids it on the grounds it is already in use. Yet AFAIK it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was google sync.

Dev-c++ couldn't save the file after editing it as google sync was using it for a long time even after it was synced.
I paused google sync, restarted my computer and then the files could be saved again.